# miniconda is not able to find packages

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, miniconda

I am trying to install tensorflow in my laptop in miniconda which says.

`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`

```
Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

The command I tried to install tensorflow is `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`
why is this happening. If you need any other information kindly ask and I will provide it.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit.

Comment: What is your OS? Linux?

Comment: it seems you are using 32bit linux, which is not supported anymore by conda-forge.

Comment: its ubuntu 16.04 LTS, my machine is 64 bit but ubuntu is 32 bit.I dont know why I did tht. any solution other than changing my OS.